# Excluir registro pelo ID em PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Boa noite, galera! 
Estou com uma dificuldade GIGANTE pra excluir uma linha do BD pelo PHP, eu imaginei o seguinte pelo código abaixo: o $linha receberia o array com todos os registros do BD,e a partir dele excluir o ID que eu quisesse, como ele está dentro de um while eu conseguiria excluir apenas esse ID. Mas o problema é que ele exclui todas as linhas do banco de dados, alguém pode me apontar o erro? Imagino que seja com o while, mas não tô conseguindo. Caso tenha alguma outra forma de excluir também agradeceria se comentasse, o código segue abaixo:

```
    <div class="row panel" style="margin-top:1%;">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
    <table>
        <h1>Jogos Cadastrados</h1>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Descrição</td>
            <td>Preço</td>
            <td>Excluir</td>
        </tr>
                <?php
        require("connect.php");
        $sql = "select * from tblgames";
        $qry = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $linha["id_game"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha["nome_game"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha["desc_game"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo "R$".$linha["preco_game"]?></td>
            <td><form method="post"><button type="submit"><input type="hidden" name="excluir">&#10005;</button></form>
            <?php 

if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
    $id = $linha["id_game"];
    $sql2     = "delete from tblgames where id_game='$id'";
    $qry2     = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
}
?>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: O erro é na lógica, nem sei como explicar, o que quer é diferente do que está escrito no código. O `while` é um loop, por isso tudo que tiver dentro será executado até que _algo_ ocorra (neste caso, até que não haja mais linhas). O `$id` (inserido no `where id_game =` é baseado no `id_game` da linha atual, por isso irá excluir tudo). Na primeira vez ele exibe os `td` e então deleta a linha, depois repete deleta a segunda, e depois... quarta... decima....

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o erro é de logica.

Seu while vai percorer todos os dados recebidos, e vai passar por todos eles, logo vai executar o delete em todos também e quando vc faz o teste

```
if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
```

uma vez que foi enviado o post com o hidden, todas as linhas serão apagadas.

Tente desta maneira

```
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $linha["id_game"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha["nome_game"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha["desc_game"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo "R$".$linha["preco_game"]?></td>
            <td>
                <form method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php $linha["id_game"]?>>
                  <button type="submit">
                  <input type="hidden" name="excluir">&#10005;</button></form>
            <?php 
if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
    $id = $_POST['id']);
    $sql2     = "delete from tblgames where id_game='$id'";
    $qry2     = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente não consegui pela forma que você colocou. Só para entender, você teria feito dois tipos "hidden", o "excluir" para executar a ação e o "id" para conter a ID correta do jogo, certo?

Comment: Sim, o excluir usaria somente para ver se a ação desejada é excluir, caso positivo, usaria o id para remover a linha da tabela, e também não colocaria dentro do while esta verificação, senão vai fazer a comparação a cada repetição do laço, colocaria antes, ai o select já viria sem o jogo excluido.

Answer (score 0):

O `$id = $linha["id_game"];` é baseado na linha atual, que é oriundo do `select * from tblgames`, *seleciona todas as colunas de todos as linhas da tabela tblgames*.

Logo, quando existe o `$_POST['excluir']` ele pega a linha atual, exclui, vai para próxima e exclui...

---

Se quer excluir um dado em especifico você pode adicionar o `value` ao `excluir`, dessa forma:

```
<form method="post"><button type="submit"><input type="hidden" name="excluir" value="<?= $linha["id_game"] ?>">&#10005;</button></form>
```

Agora o `$_POST['excluir']` terá consigo o respectivo valor do `id_game`.

---

Depois, remova o `if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){` do loop, e utilize:

```
if(isset($_POST['excluir']) && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'excluir', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false){

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['excluir']);

    $sql2     = "delete from tblgames where id_game='$id'";
    $qry2     = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

}
```

Isso irá fazer com que se existir um POST de `excluir` possuindo número irá realizar a exclusão da linha que foi enviada. Também é utilizado o `mysqli_real_escape_string` apenas por maior segurança, *embora possa ser redundante utiliza-la aqui*.

---

No final terá algo da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="row panel" style="margin-top:1%;">
<div class="medium-12 columns">
<table>
    <h1>Jogos Cadastrados</h1>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Descrição</td>
        <td>Preço</td>
        <td>Excluir</td>
    </tr>
            <?php
    require("connect.php");
    $sql = "select * from tblgames";
    $qry = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $linha["id_game"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha["nome_game"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha["desc_game"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo "R$".$linha["preco_game"]?></td>
        <td><form method="post"><button type="submit"><input type="hidden" name="excluir" value="<?= $linha["id_game"] ?>">&#10005;</button></form></td>
    </tr>
     <?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['excluir']) && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'excluir', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false){

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['excluir']);

    $sql2     = "delete from tblgames where id_game='$id'";
    $qry2     = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

}

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! mas infelizmente não funcionou, vou repassar aqui e ver se é algum erro meu de escrita. Desculpe a ignorância mas para que servem os comandos  //mysqli_real_escape_string e //filter_input? Não tinha visto eles antes. Ah, e obrigado pela explicação do erro, havia entendido de forma diferente, que só pegaria a ID que eu estivesse clicando no button

Comment: Corrigi um erro, que havia no caso do id ser `0`, o `filter_input` filtra para verificar, NESTE CASO, se é verdadeiramente um número, ao invés de por exemplo "ABC". O `mysqli_real_escape_string` para impedir/dificultar o MySQL Injection.

Comment: Ao clicar no botão a página dá refresh mas continuam os dados no bd. Coloquei um echo $id para ver se estava puxando o valor mas ele não escreveu nada, tem ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Voce fez as modificacoes

Comment: Sim, as fiz, quer que poste como ficou? 
Agora notei que você editou mais uma vez, vou testar!

Comment: Infelizmente continua sem funcionar, ele não dá erro porém não funciona a ação

Comment: Não vi que inseria o `connect.php` no meio do código, você tentou mover isto para o final, veja agora com essa edição.

Comment: Eu havia feito isso, o problema parece é que ele não puxa o valor para cima, não sei o porque :(